# When add spring-security-oauth2-client dependency get "Failed to execute goal..., Could not exec java" error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-security-oauth2

When i add this below dependency to my project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I get this error when running project using `clean spring-boot:run -Pdev` in intellij idea:

```
Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.1.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project webapp: Could not exec java
```

I also has this warning in logs:

```
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata net.minidev:json-smart/maven-metadata.xml from/to spring-milestones (https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone): Authentication failed for https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone/net/minidev/json-smart/maven-metadata.xml 401 Unauthorized
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use starters, otherwise you may have missing dependencies and unexpected exceptions

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

here is full xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```